# sense of if - how is it possible that works

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I'm watching Mojam (live games programming, on [HumbleBundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/)) and I saw this piece of code there
([here](http://puu.sh/26ySI) is screenshot of code)
I'm wondering how come the condition expression in last if statement (which is `!wasmoving && ismoving`) ever evaluates to true (it does, programmer compiled it and animation was running).
I've tried this in my compiler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    bool ismoving=5>0;
    bool wasmoving=ismoving;
    cout << "ismoving"<< ismoving << " oraz wasmoving " << wasmoving << endl;
    if (!wasmoving && ismoving) cout << "1st = true 2nd = true" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

and of course if the last if takes false path, nothing happens.
Could anyone explain how it's posssible that code from screenshot worked?

Comment: ... You're missing a crucial part where `ismoving` get's assigned to something new: `isMoving = Math.abs(velocity.x) > 0`

Comment: In that code `isJumping` and `isMoving` are changed after you get values from them.

Comment: 1st. I changed order  into wrong, 2nd boolean ismoving was declared as false. Now I get how does it work. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in the screenshot, the `ismoving` variable is updated *after* it is copied to `wasmoving`, so it is perfectly possible that the value of `ismoving` is different from the value of `wasmoving` by the time the condition is evaluated.

Comment: oh you are right bro. In class decleration there is `code` protected boolean ismoving = false `code`. I didn't pay attention about variable order. Thanx so much

Answer (score 1):

Your transformation of the code from the screenshot is inaccurate. You have changed the order of the operations.

C++ and Java, like most mainstream programming languages, are "imperative" languages. This means that programs consist of sequences of instructions that are performed one after another. When that code does:

```
boolean wasJumping = isJumping;
isJumping = ...someCalculation...;
```

That *first* sets the value of wasJumping to be the current value of isJumping, then *changes* the value of isJumping to something else. wasJumping doesn't change - it still has the old value that was taken from isJumping.

If you come from a mathematical background this can be confusing. I find it helps to read "wasJumping = isJumping" as "wasJumping *becomes* equal to isJumping", not "wasJumping equals isJumping". The former reinforces that it's describes a *change* in a variable, rather than describing a permanent relationship between two values.